# Formulating a knapsack style solution for spoj "BEHAPPY"?

Tags: algorithm, logic, dynamic-programming

The problem is described at [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BEHAPPY/) ,I have been trying to reach an iterative dp solution to the above problem.
What i can guess from my experience in coding is ,it should have three dimensions, each state uniquely identified by :-

```
M = Gifts not distributed yet.
N = first N girlfriends available (Similar to 0-1 Knapsack)
C = Maximum gifts allowable for current girlfriend.
```

Now initializing for **M=0**,N,C (i.e. When 0 gifts remain to be distributed)

```
      1 2 3 4 (girlfriends)
    0
    1
    2
    3
   (Capacity)
```

I seem to have a problem , with initialization at k=0 as there is a low and high gift limit both for girlfriends ,hence deviating from standard knapsack having only maximum limit(not considering that knapsack finds optimum solution,and here i consider all possible solution)

Of course i maybe completely on the wrong path here ,if you feel is the case, what is the recurrence and initialization for this 3 state variable dp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all the minimum requirements. `M -= sum(A[i])` and `B[i] -= A[i]`. These are the minimum so there's nothing for us to move around, just assign them and take them out of the computation.

Now your solution matrix `sol[g, m]` is the number of ways you can solve the first g girlfriends while having m gifts left. `sol[g,m] = sum(sol[g-1, m-j], j= [0..B[g-1]]`. You initialize sol[0, M] with 1 and the rest is 0.
Your solution will be sol[N+1, 0].

You only need the last line if you do it iteratively.

Comment: could you please " You initialize sol[0, M] with 1 and the rest is 0. " elaborate on this,what does intializing sol[0, M] =1 mean in practical terms. thanks

Comment: Practically yes, unless you use an allocation method that doesn't gurantee 0 by default (i.e. malloc in C gives you whatever was in the memory before).  Most languages, libraries initialize the memory with 0 by default. You can always check the documentation.